# Hidden select option with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form and I want to get this result with simple_form

```
<select>
    <option value="" hidden selected>Select your option</option>
    <option value="1">First</option>
    <option value="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

To me it seems intuitive that I could just put `placeholder: "Select your option"` but it doesn't work.

When I add `include_blank: "Select your option"` unfortunately this sentence appears in the list...

```
<%=simple_form_for :search, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :data, collection: ['First', 'Second'], include_blank: "select your option" %>
  <%= f.submit "send" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you please post your form code?

Comment: hi @RonanLopes , yes, sure!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that in Simple From or with a rails Form, you have to modify your collection, and add the `"Select your option"` to the collection.
In the array collection you pass to it the html attributes

```rb
<%= simple_form_for :search, :method => :get do |f| %>
  <%= f.input_field :data, collection: [['Select your option', "", { hidden: true }], ['First', 1], ['Second', 2]] include_blank: false, selected: "" %>
  <%= f.submit "send" %>
<% end %>
```

I was not able to find information about this in Simple From docs. But they mention in the README.me in the [Collections section](https://github.com/heartcombo/simple_form#collections), that:

> "All other options given are sent straight to the underlying Rails
> helper(s): collection_select, collection_check_boxes,
> collection_radio_buttons."

You can read more about this in the [Rails docs ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)